# idle3-tools for my external HDD

Tags: hard-disk

I am using a WD external HDD (**WDC WD10JMVW-11AJGS4**) as my system-drive for *Linux/Lubuntu 16.04.5 LTS, 64 bit*.

On http://idle3-tools.sourceforge.net/ it says under "compatibility":

> Compatibility with SATA-to-USB adapters is uncertain. Since idle3ctl
>   uses SMART ATA commands to get and set the idle3 timer, it should work
>   if SMART information can be read from your drive.

Whenever I want to access SMART-info I use the command `sudo smartctl -A -d sat /dev/sdX`. This works.
What do you think: would I be able to use **idle3-tools**?

Tnx for your opinon.

Comment: hdparm also supports idle3 (`hdparm -J`) but I've never tried to use it with USB drive

Comment: Tnx for the info. Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it might work then. However, it might be wise to try *reading* the idle3 value first (`idle3ctl -g /dev/sdX`). If it does work, setting the value should also work.

Comment: Tnx a lot for your quick answer. Well, that sounds good. Backgound of my question is: I´m looking for an alternative to **hdparm** as I seem to have run into some kind of "problem" I couldn´t find an answer to (see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084918/load-cycle-count-has-risen-temporarily)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use `hdparm -J` on an external WD My Book 1230 using a Blue WD50EZRZ drive connected through USB. I had no problems getting and setting the idle3 parameter.

`idle3ctl` was not able to detect the drive when getting the parameter so I did not try setting the parameter with it.

Versions used:
`hdparm 9.61`
`idle3-tools 0.9.1`

Comment: Thanks @Stephan for the information. In the meantime I stick to hdparm commands as well. Greetings